# gdalwarp leaves big hole at 180° longitude when warping from 4326 to custom AEqD

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp, proj

I'm trying to reproject the Natural Earth I 1:50m raster into an Azimuthal Equidistant projection centered on my hometown. As you may know, the source raster covers from -180° to 180° latitude, and -90° to 90° Here's the command I'm using:

```
gdalwarp -multi -dstnodata 0 -ot Byte -t_srs "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=48.037 +lon_0=-122.408 +ellps=sphere +units=m +no_defs" -r cubic -of GTiff -ts 10800 10800 NE1_50M_SR_W.tif natural_earth_10800.tif
```

This works pretty OK, except that it leaves a big, ugly gap west of 180°. Also, it cuts off some of each side of the output raster.

[image: Azimuthal equidistant map of the world, physical theme, with gap along International Dateline]

I've experimented with setting a radius instead of the `+ellps` parameter, with no change. Using WGS84 gives only a small slice of the Earth as output.

Here's what I got when I tried `+R_A` instead of `+ellps=sphere`:

[image: Physical map of less than a quarter of the Earth, showing North America with parts of South America and Asia]

The result with WGS84 was much the same. Also tried reprojecting to Spherical Mercator as an intermediate projection before reprojecting to my custom AEqD, same artifacts appear.

So, how do I fill in the gap? The pixels are definitely there in the input raster, they're just not making it into the output.

Comment: You might get these artefacts while reprojecting from the WGS84 ellipsoid to the sphere.

Comment: I did try using Spherical Mercator as an intermediate, thinking that would eliminate any WGS84=>sphere problems, but the same artifacts appeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got rid of the date line gap with these options:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=sphere" NE1_50M_SR_W.tif ne.tif
gdalwarp -dstnodata 0 -ot Byte -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 -t_srs "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=48.037 +lon_0=-122.408 +ellps=sphere +units=m +no_defs" -of GTiff  ne.tif neaeqd.tif
```

The `SOURCE_EXTRA` write option ensures an overlap:

> **SOURCE_EXTRA:** This is a number of extra pixels added around the source
>   window for a given request, and by default it is 1 to take care of
>   rounding error. Setting this larger will increase the amount of data
>   that needs to be read, but can avoid missing source data.

I still get a `tolerance condition error`, which might come from the antipodal point, reprojected to infinity. The cuts on the sides remain:

[image]

Comment: That did it, cheers!